# Rank an array of JSON based on dimension value in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of Javascript Objects. Need to  rank all the countries for each corporation for a given period of time based on "cr_sales_value_usd". The rank starts from 1 and goes on for a particular corporation for a time frame. Fresh ranks are given for a new company or a different time range.

Also We can have a situation where "corporation" may not exist in the data. In that case ranking is done entirely based on time. So now we rank different operating countries based on "cr_sales_value_usd" for a particular time frame.

```js
[
   {
      "cr_sales_value_usd":160276,
      "operating_country":"UK",
      "corporation":"ZERIA SHINYAKU KOG",
      "rank":null,
      "timestamp":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
   },
   {
      "cr_sales_value_usd":2745,
      "operating_country":"Norway",
      "corporation":"ZERIA SHINYAKU KOG",
      "rank":null,
      "timestamp":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
   },
   {
      "cr_sales_value_usd":2037,
      "operating_country":"Ireland",
      "corporation":"ZERIA SHINYAKU KOG",
      "rank":null,
      "timestamp":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
   },
   {
      "cr_sales_value_usd":32411301,
      "operating_country":"Germany",
      "corporation":"ZENTIVA",
      "rank":null,
      "timestamp":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
   },
   {
      "cr_sales_value_usd":470194,
      "operating_country":"Greece",
      "corporation":"ZENTIVA",
      "rank":null,
      "timestamp":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
   },
   {
      "cr_sales_value_usd":214375,
      "operating_country":"Slovakia",
      "corporation":"ZENTIVA",
      "rank":null,
      "timestamp":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
   },
   {
      "cr_sales_value_usd":2138,
      "operating_country":"Hungary",
      "corporation":"ZENTIVA",
      "rank":null,
      "timestamp":"2020-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"
   },
   {
      "cr_sales_value_usd":242,
      "operating_country":"Norway",
      "corporation":"ZENTIVA",
      "rank":null,
      "timestamp":"2020-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"
   }
]
```

I can think of a convoluted for loop type of code but looking for a cleaner solution. Thanks

Comment: Nitpick: you don't have an array of JSON. You have an array of JavaScript objects. What is your question? I didn't find it. _"Don't ask about...

    Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"_ [tour]

Comment: have you tried playing with [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. Please try it yourself and ask about a specific problem you encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I understand correctly, you would like to sort the objects in the array based on the value of the `cr_sales_value_usd` key.

If so, this should do the trick:

```
arr.sort((a, b) => a.cr_sales_value_usd - b.cr_sales_value_usd);
```

So simply apply

```
sort((a, b) => a.cr_sales_value_usd - b.cr_sales_value_usd);
```

on the array of objects.